# CSS footer at the bottom with jQuerymobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, footer

Same question successfully resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544999/css-footer-at-the-bottom-with-certain-conditions) but using jquerymobile

here is the script the working script, without jQmobile
http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/tCdPX/12/

now just adding the jQmobile script and link head tag:
http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/tCdPX/13/

doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery mobile adds a page wrapper with the class `ui-page`. It needs the css definition `height: 100%;` too.

Add the class `ui-page` to the css defintion for html and body:

```
html, body, .ui-page {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also see [your updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/tCdPX/14/).

Answer (score 0):

My best solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html, body, .ui-page").height($(window).height());
}
```

Hope this helps.